# Setting up LocalStorage using data attributes

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I have 2 different types of buttons that I want to save users selections into localStorage and display in a 'cart'. I am having trouble figuring out how to separate them. Right now everything from both is being shown.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1q17uz3y/)

Every button will have a different value set in the data-attribute, but there are two types of values - floor plans and properties.

JS:

```
function showElem1() {
    var $ul = $('<ul />', { "class": "cart1" });
      for (var a = 0, len = localStorage.length; a < len; a++)   {
        var $li = $('<li />', { text: localStorage.key(a) });
        $('<span />', { "class": "removeitem", data: { remove: localStorage.key(a) }, html: " <i class='icon-trash2'></i>" })
          .appendTo($li);
        $li.appendTo($ul);
      }
    $ul.appendTo($('.cart1').empty());
};    

function showElem2() {
    var $ul = $('<ul />', { "class": "cart2" });
      for (var a = 0, len = localStorage.length; a < len; a++)   {
        var $li = $('<li />', { text: localStorage.key(a) });
        $('<span />', { "class": "removeitem", data: { remove: localStorage.key(a) }, html: " <i class='icon-trash2'></i>" })
          .appendTo($li);
        $li.appendTo($ul);
      }
    $ul.appendTo($('.cart2').empty());
};

showElem1();
showElem2();

$("body").on('click', '.property', function() {
    if(!localStorage.getItem($(this).data('property'))) {
          localStorage.setItem($(this).data('property'), 0 );
    }                         
     showElem1();
});

$("body").on('click', '.floor-plan', function() {        
    if(!localStorage.getItem($(this).data('floorplan'))) {
          localStorage.setItem($(this).data('floorplan'), 1 );
    }                 
     showElem2();
});


$(".cart").on('click', '.removeitem', function() {
    localStorage.removeItem($(this).data('remove'));
    showElem1();
    showElem2();
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="cart">
       <div class="cart1"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="cart">
       <div class="cart2"></div>
 </div>

 <a data-property="Tri Estate, Kennewick, WA" class="property"> Add to Selections</a>

 <a data-floorplan="Floor Plan 1" class="floor-plan">Add Floorplan</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see,
You didn't check type of items you want to show in 2 function showElem1 and showElem2.

Thanks,

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Hi @dchadney, follow your code, maybe you want to add a prefix to data attribute to detect type of value. e.g: data-property="0|Tri Estate, Kennewick, WA" and data-floorplan="1|Floor Plan 1". When read from  localStorage, just check the first character is 0 or 1, when get text remember to remove 2 first character.